# How to remain at a scroll position in RecyclerView after adding items at its first index?

Tags: android, vertical-scrolling, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView in my app, appending more items to a `RecyclerView` after its last item makes the RecyclerView's scroll remain at its position but when I add items before the first item, the scroll position moves up to the newly first item added. How can I maintain my scroll position after adding new items at its first index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecyclerView has a method `yourRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(int_position_value);` you just need to pass this method your position and it will scroll down or up depending on position. Now what you have to do is after appending item/items calculate the position where you want to scroll and pass it to this method.

Comment: What did you mean by calculating the position? To maintain the scroll position exactly where it was before the items were added at 0th index I need to calculate the height of all those items?

Comment: No you do not need to calculate height, all you have to do is calculate how many items you have added/removed let say you want to maintain your scroll position at 10th item after adding some items, then just pass the above method a value of 10 or 9 depending if it is a zero index